# Tapping the screen to bring back from screen dimming without registering the tap

Tags: 7.0-nougat, touchscreen

I had been an iOS user for the past 10 years. Now I have switched to LG G6 Android phone.

There are quite a few quirks that I somehow find very disturbing. 
For example this:

I have set the screen dimming at 1 minute. When I tap the screen after it has dimmed after 1 minute inactivity, it registers the a tab on the screen. In iOS you could touch anywhere on the screen, it would just remove the dimming effect but it wouldn't register a tap.

I am not trying to wake the device from sleep. I am trying to wake from the dimmed state.

Is it possible solve this problem?

Comment: I am not trying to wake the phone from sleep. I am trying to wake from the dimmed state.

Comment: it locks the screen.